# Why this Python pandas DataFrame code does not work?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

income_vs_hardship = %sql SELECT per_capita_income_, hardship_index FROM chicago_socioeconomic_data;
plot = sns.jointplot(x='per_capita_income_',y='hardship_index', data=pd.DataFrame(income_vs_hardship))
```

Correct answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

income_vs_hardship = %sql SELECT per_capita_income_, hardship_index FROM chicago_socioeconomic_data;
plot = sns.jointplot(x='per_capita_income_',y='hardship_index', data=income_vs_hardship.DataFrame())
```

The only difference:
`data=pd.DataFrame(income_vs_hardship)` vs. `data=income_vs_hardship.DataFrame()`

If DataFrame is a method belongs to pandas, why my code does not work.
The error shows 'unable to interpret the per_capita_income.'

Comment: Because you're using the `%sql` magic, the variable is a sql return, not a normal pandas call to the `pd.DataFrame()` constructor. I wonder if your original code would work if you used `pd.read_sql()` instead. One other thing to check would be to try creating the dataframe outside the seaborn call, and see whether the dataframe is properly created

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame` is a class of the pandas module, not a method that you can apply to a DataFrame instance.

`income_vs_hardship.DataFrame()` can't be interpreted by Python, as `income_vs_hardship` has no `DataFrame` method. Instead, `pd.DataFrame(income_vs_hardship)` creates a DtaFrame object.

Comment: While normally this is true, it's is actually not the case in this instance. (note: OP stated that the version with `.DataFrame()` is the code that _does_ work. This is due to the apparent use of the `%sql` magic in ipython. [This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-magics-with-sql-921370099589) has a good overview

Comment: Yes. Let me make it clear.  income_vs_hardship.DataFrame() works and pd.DataFrame(income_vs_hardship) does not work